# How to bridge the gap between Wikipedia database dump and GATE?

Tags: nlp, wikipedia, gate

the overall task is do NLP on Wikipedia pages.

First thing is to access the downloaded Wikipedia database dump(40GB XML file) from GATE in a good way?
Actually, I need only the medical category.

is there some libraries for this?

any hints is appreciated!

BW

Answer (score 0):

So far as I searched, seems I have to :
1. Install a Mediawiki locally
2. use mwdump to import the xml dump into the Mediawiki database(MySQL)
3. access the MySQL database using JDBC connector

don't know if I am detouring